# Correcting incorrect spacy label

Tags: python, spacy

I try to use Spacy to syntactically parse the following sentence:

```
my_sentence = "delete failed setup"
```

So I do the following:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en")
doc = nlp(my_sentence)
```

However, Spacy does not recognize this sentence as an imperative, and thinks "delete" is a proper noun (PROPN) here, whereas it believes "failed" to be the verb.

Is there any way to nudge Spacy in the right direction, as it were? In particular, I have some domain knowledge so I know that this particular verb, "delete", is very likely to be a verb, not a noun.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#training). Maybe you can train a custom model if you have the domain knowledge

Comment: spaCy's English models are trained on a variety of text but mostly newspaper articles or similar things, so they just don't see a lot of imperative usage. You can train your own model if you have a corpus, but if your extra knowledge is just something like "delete is probably a verb" there's not really any way to make use of that.

Comment: You can try using a larger corpus such as en_core_web_lg. This problem occurs on sm but not on lg when I tested in your example sentece. However, some other sentences still have the same issue. Maybe a hacky solution can be replacing known verb and adjective words with words that will definitely be tagged as verb and adjective before creating a doc and replacing them after it is done.

Answer (score -1):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = ("delete the failed setup")
doc = nlp(text)

print("Noun phrases:", [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
print("Verbs:", [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ == "VERB"])

for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

**output**

```
Noun phrases: ['the failed setup']

Verbs: ['delete', 'fail']
```